# gmap.net can't see the map

Tags: c#, gmap.net

i'm using Gmap.net in Windows Form. I've added references to .dll files than dragged GmapControl to the form and added this code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
     gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
     GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.CacheOnly;
     gmap.SetCurrentPositionByKeywords("Maputo, Mozambique");
}
```

and when I runn it it just shows me the bright control with the red cross in the middle, and the blue text in the bottom "Google-map...."

anny suggestions how could i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Set your zoom level and set access mode to cacheAndServer

```
private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
    gMapControl1.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
    GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
    gMapControl1.Position = new PointLatLng(LATITUDE,LONGITUDE);
    gMapControl1.Zoom = 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the AccessMode to 'ServerOnly'.
I hope to be helpful!
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue  , you should set Min Zoom Property of GMap control to Zero